# Cleaner way to write this try/catch block? Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I use a try/catch when working with transactions. The code would first try to get an entity and if it catches an EntityNotFoundException, it would try to create the entity. The problem is, since I am working with transactions, I also need to catch ConcurrentModificationException when putting the entity. The code looks somewhat like this:

```
try {
   datastore.get(key);
} catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
   try {
      datastore.put(entity);
   } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
      // retry or log exception
   }
}
```

This looks pretty ugly though. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to write this?

Comment: Could you explain why the fact that you are working with transactions causes yo to catch `ConcurrentModificationException`. Something looks strange for me here.

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding the docs wrong here. My understanding is that ConcurrentModificationException is thrown if someone else is also trying to the put a entity with the same key. In this case, I am working with a root entity, so writes will not be locked. So someone could create the entity after the get() returns nothing but before put() is executed. Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you could consider using Objectify - its an object mapper specifically for appengine, and has more elegant handling of transactions.

Comment: Why do you think this looks ugly? It describes your logic pretty concisely. You can use generics and lambdas to wrap it in a method, if you need this logic in multiple places and you don't want to repeat yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with methods to keep it flat.

```
try {
   datastore.get(key);  
} catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
   createEntity(entity);
}

private void createEntity(Object entity){ //Replace Object with the correct type
    try{
        datastore.put(entity);
    }catch (ConcurrentModificationException  e) {
        //Handling both errors
    }
}
```

This will untangle the try-catch-blocks a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a separate method E.g.

```
  public static KeyValue get(DataStore datastore, Key key){ //assume this method is in Util class

               try {
               return datastore.get(key);
             } catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
                 return null;
          }
       }
```

// now implementation

```
       KeyValue value = Util.get(datastore, key);

         if(value!=null){

                     // do your steps
          }
         else{
               // create
         }
```